# How to open .ttcn file using C file open functions?

Tags: c, file, scripting, ttcn

I am working on TTCN-3 (Testing and Test Control Notation) scripting language. I wanted to prepare on guideline checker for this code files.

For that I want to read lines of TTCN-3 script file( some thing like file.ttcn ) one by one into a buffer. But for me fopen / sopen / open / fgetc / fscanf are not able to work properly and are not reading the file correctly. It is giving NULL. Is there any way I can read characters of it into a buffer. I think C cannot read files with more than three extension characters (like .ttcn). Forgive me if my assumption is wrong.

My Environment is Turbo C on windows.

**Edit**:

Yes I checked those errors also but they are giving unknown error for read()
and no such file or directory exists.

My code is as follows

```
#include <errno.h>
 #include <io.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys\stat.h>
 #include <process.h>
 #include <share.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    int handle;
    int status;
    int i=0;
    char ch;

    FILE *fp;
    char *buffer;
    char *buf;
    clrscr();
    handle = sopen("c:\\tc\\bin\\hi.ttcn", O_BINARY, SH_DENYNONE, S_IREAD);
```

/*here even I used O_TEXT and others*/

```
    if (!handle)
    {
       printf("sopen failed\n");
   //    exit(1);
    }

   printf("\nObtained string %s @",buf);

    close(handle);

    fp=fopen("c:\\tc\\bin\\hi.ttcn","r");  \\sorry for the old version of one slash
   if(fp==NULL)                            \\I was doing it with argv[1] for opening 
   {                                       \\user given file name 
     printf("\nCannot open file");
   }
    ch=fgetc(fp);
   i=0;
   while(i<10)
   {
     printf("\ncharacter is %c  %d",ch,ch);
     i++;                                    //Here I wanted to take characters into 
     ch=fgetc(fp);                           //buffer   
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong about extensions. If fopen is returning NULL, you should output the result of strerror(errno) or use the perror() function to see why it failed.

**Edit**: The problem is probably because you have "c:\tc\bin\hi.ttcn". in C, "\t" is interpreted as tab, for example.

You could do

```
"c:\\tc\\bin\\hi.ttcn"
```

But this is extremely ugly, and your system should accept:

```
"c:/tc/bin/hi.ttcn"
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprit is your Turbo C, an ancient compiler. It's techincally a DOS compiler, not Windows. That would limit it's RunTme Library to 8.3 filenames. Upgrade to something newer - Turbo C++ seems like a logical successor, but Microsoft's VC++ Express would work as well.

Comment: If the 8.3 filename limitation is the problem, you can open a Command Prompt window and use the command DIR /X to show the "short name" version of your .ttcn file.  (For compatibility reasons, Windows allows any non 8.3-format filename to *also* be referenced by an 8.3-format filename.)

Comment: ya I know that but I tried to know the solution for this scenario.

Comment: Ok
Thank you Mr. j_random_hacker for teaching me this.
I got the answer by your comment. You gave me real answer what is needed but in a comment. If you have given that as an answer I would have voted you and accepted as correct answer. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

MS-DOS does not know about long file names, thos including files with extensions longer than 3 characters. Therefore, the CRT provided by Turbo C most probably does not look for the name you are providing, but a truncated one - or something else.

Windows conveniently provides a short (i.e. matching the 8.3 format, most of the time ending in ~1 unless you play with files having the same 8-character prefix) file name for those; one way to discover it is to open a console window and to run "dir /x" in the folder your file is stored.

Find the short name associated to your file and patch it into your C source file.

Edit: Darn, I'll read the comments next time. All credits to j_random_hacker.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've posted the code, another problem comes to light.

The following line:

```
fp=fopen("c:\tc\bin\hi.ttcn","r");
```

Should instead read:

```
fp=fopen("c:\\tc\\bin\\hi.ttcn","r");
```

In C strings, the backslash (`\`) is an *escape character* that is used to encode special characters (e.g. `\n` represents a newline character, `\t` a tab character).  To actually use a literal backslash, you need to double it.  As it stands, the compiler is actually trying to open a file named `"C:<tab>c<backspace>in\hi.ttcn"` -- needless to say, no such file exists!

Comment: okok I was such a fool I edited my code for better understanding by replacing argv[1] with the file path but I didn't thought of this one while pasting it here. Thanks

Comment: Relax, we've all made this mistake at least once...  :)