# How to dynamically get the filename according to extension?

Tags: c, file, winapi, ttcn

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515171/how-to-open-ttcn-file-using-c-file-open-functions) ....

Now I found the answer for that question by a comment  by user j_random_hacker. Here Windows follows 8.3 file naming standard means turbo c can only read files with name length of 8 characters and extension of 3 characters. So windows will give another name to any file which is not following 8.3 naming standard. Like in my case Windows was giving **HIBDS~1.TTC** for the actual file name of **HI.TTCN** .

Now my problem is I want to take that file name as an argument at runtime as shown below

> `glc hi.ttcn`
>
> Here glc is my .exe file which will check the coding guidelines violations and hi.ttcn is the actual TTCN file to be checked. So here the problem is as told above windows is giving some other name to hi.ttcn so my program is not able to open that file saying "File name does not exists" because I am giving the same argument string "hi.ttcn" to fopen. So how can I get the windows allocated file name at run time for the given argument string ( means I want to get the string "HIBDS~1.TTC" when "HI.TTCN" is given.)

Answer (score 3):

Alright, here's the page describing the Win32 function you'll need to call:

[GetShortPathName Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(VS.85).aspx)

You'll need to `#include <windows.h>` at the top of your program, and probably jump through a bunch more hoops to get this to compile on such an old compiler (maybe Turbo C didn't even ship with Windows headers?)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done, but it's tricky as it requires delving into hairy Win32 API calls.  It will be *much* easier to simply recompile using a modern compiler -- is there any reason why this can't be done?

Here are links to two free, high quality C/C++ compilers that will have no trouble with long filenames: [Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/); [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: ok thank you again. But still I cant install softwares on my own on an office PC. So I am sticking to what my office administrator installed ie "Turbo C". I will see other options also .. But still if you have any method please inform me. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dir /x` to get short file names from the command line

Comment: ya but you should hav seen the old question for which this question is follow up. I already got this answer for that question. Now my question is how to get it inside a program at runtime with the user supplied file name.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a useful approach -- it's possible that running system("dir /x myfile.tttc > temp") and parsing temp is easier than calling GetShortPathName()!